# Mapping data with hooks in React after new data submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is I print the list of movies with `map` and I want the list to automatically print after submit without refreshing the page:

```
  const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState('');
  const [movieReview, setMovieReview] = useState('');
  const [movieReviewsList, setMovieReviewsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get')
      .then((response) => {
        setMovieReviewsList(response.data);
      })
    }, []);

    const submitReview = () => {
    
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
      movieName: movieName, 
      movieReview: movieReview,
    });
    
    setMovieReviewsList([...movieReviewsList, {
      movieName: movieName, 
      movieReview: movieReview
    }]);
  }
```

After database submit, I add a newly added movie to the list and try to map it so that a new movie will appear without refreshing the page:

```
{movieReviewsList.map((movie) => {
  return (
   <div key={movie.idmovie_reviews}>
     <h3>Movie name: {movie.movie_name} </h3>
     <h3>Movie review: </h3>
     <p>{movie.movie_review}</p>
   </div>
  );
})}
```

I don't add a key when inserting the value to the database, where in my SQL db it is auto-incremented. Is there any way to add it so that I will be able to map it without refreshing?

Comment: Can you make your /api/insert endpoint return the inserted movie back?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue description is so short to solve.
I guess your `form` is submitted into server as sync.

```
const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ...
}

<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  // ...
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```